# c - Quick q about overflow detection

Tags: c, buffer, overflow

```
int array[100];
int *ptr = &array[102];
```

Supposing that there was some way to precisely detect buffer overflow, when will this code experience a buffer overflow? Is it compile time? My research tells me no, but I'm not sure.

Comment: This code does nothing *per se*, please show a minimal test code.

Comment: A static analysis tool or a very smart compiler might be able to pick up this error, but you typically won't see a problem until you read or write via `ptr`, at run-time.

Comment: @ouah I was referring to the invalid ptr assignment. It's a hypothetical question.

Comment: @PaulR Meaning, for example, if I attempted to dereference ptr and assign its value to an int variable?

Comment: @Sara the second declaration invokes undefined behavior, in practice as soon as you write to `*ptr` your buffer is overflown.

Comment: Thanks! @ouah That was my intuition, but I wasn't sure.